# Skipping Blank Excel Cells in Apache POI

Tags: java, apache-poi

I'm new to the Apache POI, but what I want to do is read though an Excel file (.xls) and put that into a ArrayList to store so that I can later manipulate. I can get the whole sheet, but my problem is just that: I get the whole dang sheet (~54183 rows).

I want to skip over the cells that are blank, which is of type 3. For some reason, when I system.out.print the ArrayList, it has all the blank cells in there.

Is there a way to skip over those and not add them to the ArrayList I'm trying to create?

I have the following bit of code:

```
public ArrayList readExcelFile(String filePath) throws IOException {
    ArrayList cellVectorHolder = new ArrayList();
    try {
        FileInputStream inputFile = new FileInputStream(filePath);
        POIFSFileSystem myFileSystem = new POIFSFileSystem(inputFile);
        HSSFWorkbook wkbk = new HSSFWorkbook(myFileSystem);
        wb = wkbk;
        for (int i = 0; i < wb.getNumberOfSheets(); i++) {
            HSSFSheet wkSheet = wkbk.getSheetAt(i);
            for (Row row : wkSheet) {
                ArrayList cellVector = new ArrayList();
                for (Cell cell : row) {
                    if(cell.getCellType() != 3){
                        cellVector.add(cell);
                    }
                }
                cellVectorHolder.add(cellVector);
            }
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return cellVectorHolder;
}
```

Don't mind the ArrayList names...I was using Vectors until I finally discovered they were depreciated since 1.2 or something like that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Before adding the cell to the List, you can check the cell value. Something like:

```
if (cell.getStringCellValue() != null &&  cell.getStringCellValue().length() != 0) {   
    cellVector.add(cell); 
}
```

You only add the cell if there is some content.

Comment: Yeah, this is what I finally resorted to. A few if else statements to check it. I was just hoping for some short clean way that the POI would have. Thank you though for the push in the right direction!

Comment: cell.getStringCellValue() will throw an IllegalStateException if the cell type is other then text (e.g. numeric).

Answer (score 1):

I think you should iterate over the rows and cells, that way POI won't even give you the empty cells.

Checkout the `HSSFSheet.iterator()` which iterates over all the Rows in a Sheet.
And then `Row.cellIterator()` which iterates over the Cells in that row.

And you are bascially done.

If you are intent on keeping your old result variables your two inner loops becomes:

```
for (Iterator<Row> rit = wkSheet.iterator();rit.hasNext();) {
    ArrayList cellVector = new ArrayList();
    for(Iterator<Cell> cit = rit.next().cellIterator(); cit.hasNext(); ) { 
            cellVector.add(cit.next());
    }
    cellVectorHolder.add(cellVector);
}
```

Comment: You probably also want to check the type against CELL_TYPE_BLANK - Excel will often leave cells in the file that have been used once and are now empty with this type.

Comment: Hm, even if you check for CELL_TYPE_BLANK? I've never experienced anything like that. When I read your code I kinda thought you went out of your way to include the empty cells.

Comment: So I went back and did the Cell_Type_Blank with the iterator, and that will still put blank cells into my arrayList, but only from one sheet. I added another check for "" and that seemed to get rid of them. Thanks for the help esej!

Comment: Cool. Cells with type CELL_TYPE_BLANK and with cellValue "" ought to come from the source (for example somebody manually editing an excel file). Completely empty cells aren't saved in the file. But if there was a value there and then the value got deleted the cell info would be in the file.

Answer (score 1):

```
Try the following code with excel as 
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Cell;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Row;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Sheet;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Workbook;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook;
public class excelDataReader {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    List<Info> infoList = extractInfo();
    for (Info info : infoList) {
        System.out.println(info);
    }
}
public static List<Info> extractInfo() {
    List<Info> infoList = new ArrayList<Info>();
    Workbook wb = null;
    try {
        wb = new XSSFWorkbook(new FileInputStream(new         
 File("C:\\Users\\rrr\\Downloads\\contacts.xlsx")));
        Sheet sheet = wb.getSheetAt(0);
        boolean skipHeader = true;
        for (Row row : sheet) {
            if (skipHeader) {
                skipHeader = false;
                continue;
            }
            List<Cell> cells = new ArrayList<Cell>();
            int lastColumn = Math.max(row.getLastCellNum(), 5);// because my
                                                                // excel
                                                                // sheet has
                                                                // max 5
                                                                // columns,
                                                                // in case
                                                                // last
                                                                // column is
                                                                // empty
                                                                // then
                                                                // row.getLastCellNum()
                                                                // will
                                                                // return 4
            for (int cn = 0; cn < lastColumn; cn++) {
                Cell c = row.getCell(cn, Row.RETURN_BLANK_AS_NULL);
                cells.add(c);
            }
            Info info = extractInfoFromCell(cells);
            infoList.add(info);
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        if (wb != null) {
            try {
                wb.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
    return infoList;
}
private static Info extractInfoFromCell(List<Cell> cells) {
    Info info = new Info();
    Cell nameCell = cells.get(0);
    if (nameCell != null) {
        nameCell.setCellType(Cell.CELL_TYPE_STRING);
        info.setName(nameCell.getStringCellValue());
    }
    Cell mobileCell = cells.get(1);
    if (mobileCell != null) {
        mobileCell.setCellType(Cell.CELL_TYPE_STRING);
        info.setMobile(mobileCell.getStringCellValue());
    }
    Cell phoneCell = cells.get(2);
    if (phoneCell != null) {
        phoneCell.setCellType(Cell.CELL_TYPE_STRING);
        info.setPhone(phoneCell.getStringCellValue());
    }
    Cell permAddressCell = cells.get(3);
    if (permAddressCell != null) {
        permAddressCell.setCellType(Cell.CELL_TYPE_STRING);
        info.setPermAddress(permAddressCell.getStringCellValue());
    }
    Cell commAddressCell = cells.get(4);
    if (commAddressCell != null) {
        commAddressCell.setCellType(Cell.CELL_TYPE_STRING);
        info.setCommAddress(commAddressCell.getStringCellValue());
    }
    return info;
}
```

}
    package cmprocesser.cmprocesser;

```
import java.io.File; 
import java.io.FileInputStream;  
import java.io.IOException;  
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFCell;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFSheet;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.LinkedHashMap;
import java.util.List;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Cell;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Comment;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Row;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Sheet;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Workbook;

public class Info {
    private String name;
    private String mobile;
    private String phone;
    private String permAddress;
    private String commAddress;
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
    public String getMobile() {
        return mobile;
    }
    public void setMobile(String mobile) {
        this.mobile = mobile;
    }
    public String getPhone() {
        return phone;
    }
    public void setPhone(String phone) {
        this.phone = phone;
    }
    public String getPermAddress() {
        return permAddress;
    }
    public void setPermAddress(String permAddress) {
        this.permAddress = permAddress;
    }
    public String getCommAddress() {
        return commAddress;
    }
    public void setCommAddress(String commAddress) {
        this.commAddress = commAddress;
    }
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Info [Name=" + name + ", Mobile=" + mobile + ", Phone=" + phone + ", Permanent Address=" + permAddress
                + ", Communication Address=" + commAddress + "]";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
List cellDataList = new ArrayList
HSSFWorkbook workBook = new HSSFWorkbook(fsFileSystem);
                            HSSFSheet hssfSheet = workBook.getSheetAt(0);
                            Iterator rowIterator = hssfSheet.rowIterator();

                            int lineNumber = 0;
                            while (rowIterator.hasNext())
                            {
                                HSSFRow hssfRow = (HSSFRow) rowIterator.next();

                                lineNumber++;
                                if(lineNumber==1){continue;}



                                Iterator iterator = hssfRow.cellIterator();
                                List cellTempList = new ArrayList();
                                int current = 0, next = 1;
                                while (iterator.hasNext())
                                {
                                    HSSFCell hssfCell = (HSSFCell) iterator.next();

                                    current = hssfCell.getColumnIndex();


                                    if(current<next){                                   


                                    }
                                    else{

                                        int loop = current-next;

                                        for(int k=0;k<loop+1;k++){


                                            cellTempList.add(null);
                                            next = next + 1;
                                        }
                                    }

                                    cellTempList.add(hssfCell);



                                    next = next + 1;



                                }
                                cellDataList.add(cellTempList);
                            }
```