# Java POI. skip cell when blank

Tags: java, excel, javafx, apache-poi

I get an error: "Cannot get a NUMERIC value from a STRING cell" and I'm sure this is because the cell is blank. I am reading data from xlsx and writing it onto my database. Does anyone have an easy method to just skip the blank cell and progress on?

```
       FileInputStream fileIn = new FileInputStream(filename);
      Workbook wb = new XSSFWorkbook(fileIn);
        Sheet sheet = wb.getSheetAt(0);

        SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy");


        Row row; 
      for  (int i=1; i<=sheet.getLastRowNum(); i++){
            row = sheet.getRow(i);


            pst.setObject(1, row.getCell(0).getNumericCellValue());
            pst.setString(2, row.getCell(1).getStringCellValue());
            pst.setObject(3, sdf.format(row.getCell(2).getDateCellValue()));
            pst.setObject(4, sdf.format(row.getCell(3).getDateCellValue()));
            pst.setString(5, row.getCell(4).getStringCellValue());
            pst.setObject(6, sdf.format(row.getCell(5).getDateCellValue()));
            pst.setDouble(1, row.getCell(0).getNumericCellValue());
            pst.execute();
                        }


        wb.close();
        fileIn.close();
        pst.close();
        rs.close();
loadDataFromDatabase();
}catch (SQLException  ex){
            Logger.getLogger(TestTableController.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE,null,ex);
        }catch (IOException ex){
            Logger.getLogger(TestTableController.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE,null,ex);
        }
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Skipping Blank Excel Cells in Apache POI](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10405557/skipping-blank-excel-cells-in-apache-poi)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Ram Alapure from Youtube for his help. 
Two things to keep in mind when i was trying to import data from Excel.
1.Highlight all empty cells and clear content. Prior to that  I would get 
error Cannot get a  NUMERIC  value from a STRING cell and if i change from getStringCellValue() to getDateCellValue() i would get error Cannot get a  STRING value from a NUMERIC  cell. it was like Schrödinger's cat

2. use a try catch for NullPointerException.

Below is my working code.

```
FileInputStream fileIn = new FileInputStream(filename);
      Workbook wb = new XSSFWorkbook(fileIn);
        Sheet sheet = wb.getSheetAt(0);

        SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy");



        Row row; 


  for (int i=1; i<=sheet.getLastRowNum(); i++){
            row = sheet.getRow(i);

            System.out.println(row.getCell(5)); 
            try{

                    if(row.getCell(5).getDateCellValue() ==  null){
Date date = new Date(); // set any default value
pst.setObject(6, null); // or you can set it to null if null is allowed   i.e. pst.setObject(6, null);
 }else{
pst.setObject(6, sdf.format(row.getCell(5).getDateCellValue()));
                    }


            pst.setObject(1, row.getCell(0).getNumericCellValue());
            pst.setString(2, row.getCell(1).getStringCellValue());
            pst.setObject(3, sdf.format(row.getCell(2).getDateCellValue()));
            pst.setObject(4, sdf.format(row.getCell(3).getDateCellValue()));
            pst.setString(5, row.getCell(4).getStringCellValue());
            pst.setObject(6, sdf.format(row.getCell(5).getDateCellValue()));
            pst.setDouble(7, row.getCell(6).getNumericCellValue());

            }catch(NullPointerException NPE)

          {

             }

            pst.execute();

    }


        wb.close();
        fileIn.close();
        pst.close();
        rs.close();
loadDataFromDatabase();
}catch (SQLException  ex){
            Logger.getLogger(TestTableController.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE,null,ex);
        }catch (IOException ex){
            Logger.getLogger(TestTableController.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE,null,ex);
        }
            }
}
```